# How does browser resolve unregistered domains like .ph or .ws?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-name

If we visit an unregistered domain like http://no-domain-here.ph/ we get a webpage from ph registry

However, this domain doesn't have any ns records associated. How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

And it depends a lot on which recusive nameserver your browser is using, as it can be lying. Also, it happens more and more today that browsers like Firefox or Google Chrome are able to use DoH (DNS over HTTPS) and hence any external server to do DNS resolution

So whatever DNS resolver you are using can lie to you if a domain does not exist and respond in such a way that your browser will be directed through some specific page. Various extensions or configuration items in your browser can also get you the same behaviour.

But for your specific example, it works because the registry of .PH has a wildcard in its zone.

You can check it easily:

```
$ dig ph. NS +short
1.ns.ph.
ns2.cuhk.edu.hk.
ph.communitydns.net.
ns4.apnic.net.
$ dig \*.ph A @1.ns.ph. +noall +ans +nottlunits
*.ph.           300 IN A 45.79.222.138
```

This wildcard means that, no matter which name you query for, if there are no other records (a real registered name), you will get this IP address. Note that the wildcard applies only to `A`:

```
$ dig \*.ph AAAA @1.ns.ph. +noall +ans +nottlunits
(no data)
$ dig \*.ph NS @1.ns.ph. +noall +ans +nottlunits
(no data)
```

This case is only possible for ccTLDs (but few do it) because it is prohibited in gTLDs by ICANN rules, after the infamous Verisign SiteFinder "experiment" in the past.

And when this happens, it does not impact just a browser and HTTP traffic, but everything. Which is root of the problem: imagine there is a valid `example.ph` domain and you have to send an highly sensitive information (and not encrypting the message), to `medical@example.ph` but you do a typo and send to `medical@exanple.ph` where this `exanple.ph` domain does not exist... but it will resolve and per SMTP rules, even without `MX` record, the message will be sent over to the IP address (wildcard) that `exanple.ph` resolves to, and then it depends if an MTA is listening there or not.

`.ws` ccTLD (yes it is a country) has the same kind of wildcard:

```
$ dig ws. NS +short
ns5.dns.ws.
us3.dns.ws.
us4.dns.ws.
a.dns.ws.
ns2.dns.ws.
s.dns.ws.
$ dig @s.dns.ws \*.ws. A +noall +ans +nottlunits
*.ws.           300 IN A 64.70.19.203
```